# Trying to get a java program to connect to a local Mysql Database on Mac

Tags: java, mysql, database, database-connection

I'm trying to build an Jframe app that gets information from a local mysql database and fills in a list view in the GUI. I can't get the program to connect to the database. I'm on a Mac and I was wondering if it is something to with permissions in the OS or if I'm just missing something in the code.

```
package dataBaseConnection;
    import java.sql.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class DBConnection 
    {

        public static Connection dbConnection()
        {   
            try 
            {
                String driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
                String url = "jdbc:mysql://mysql@localhost:3306/login";
                String username = "root";
                String password = "TestTestTestTest";

                Class.forName(driver);

                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connected to the database");

                return conn;
            }

            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Could not connect to the database...");

                return null;
            }
        }
    }


    package dataBaseConnection;

    import java.awt.EventQueue;
    import java.sql.*;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;

    public class Login {

        private JFrame frame;

        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
            {
                public void run() 
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        Login window = new Login();
                        window.frame.setVisible(true);
                    } 
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        DBConnection myConn = new DBConnection();

        public Login() 
        {
            initialize();
            DBConnection.dbConnection();
        }

        private void initialize() 
        {
            frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }

    }
```

No matter what I try I can't find my problem. It will not connect to my local mysql database.

The Exception is: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: How did you add the mysql-jdbc jar?

Comment: Added it to the build path under libraries in eclipse.

Comment: Could you add the exception you got in your post

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your credentials to the MySQL, check the username and password

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

, you can check using the terminal with the username and the password

```
$ mysql -u root -p
```

If you forget the password review How to reset it

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after I printed the error. It was two issues first one was the login password. Got that fixed. But I was getting a TimeZone error.

Second error: java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'MDT' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.

Got that fixed by passing the timeZone through the client with the url.

"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC";

This fixed it.